# How to edit Excel(.xlsx) documents using python - but without using any non-standard modules?

Tags: python, excel, standard-library

Is there a way to edit an Excel document in python without using any modules that are made to work with Excel documents? I'm not looking for external libraries, I'd like to learn about how to do it on my own.

My goal is to make a program that will scan my progress in my online classes, and update the .xlsx accordingly.

Comment: Answering your question may rob you of an excellent opportunity to learn how to do things without any pre-made code.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski - So did that comment have any logic behind it, or are you just being salty?

Comment: The logic is that you have the ability to search "python standard library" yourself, and scan over the modules that are provided

Comment: In my distribution, there aren't any modules that are made to work with excel, and that's not what I am looking for anyway.         Update: I have edited the question to reflect what I want more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

If by "modules that are[] automatically included in python" you mean those that are included in a major distribution of Python, several modules that work with Excel are included in [the Anaconda distribution](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs). Many of these, such as xlwings and xlsxwriter, are automatically installed with Anaconda, while some others require a simple conda install.

A list of Anaconda modules more specific to Excel is [here](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/excel).

Comment: Thank you for the response and the info provided, but I was looking for a way to do it without using modules that are made to be used with Excel docs.